# How to fix Anylogic Unable to open the model Error?

Tags: java, anylogic

I was working on a model and while creating a node network, I believe I added a route with length 0 and now I had to close the model and won't open. I had to terminate Anylogic, and while try to open the autosave file I am getting the following error:

[image]

Is there any way to fix this? I lost a lot of work...

Comment: What if you open the original file (not auto-save)? Also, you can try to open the auto-save in a notepad and edit what you think might cause this, but you can easily corrupt the file, so make a backup first

Comment: When trying to open the original no auto save model, it gives me the option to replace the file with the latest I saved, but I lose like 5 hours of work. I did try to delete that last path from the code using the notepad, but it gives me the invalid project file format error.... Any more suggestions? @Benjamin

Comment: Only try to change the notepad file very carefully, to preserve the xml format (else you get the format error). Oh, and get into the habit of saving manually all the time. And even more important: Start using GitHub for versioning, saves you a ton of this frustration